# Outgoing longwave radiation for SEBAL

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript

I am finishing to create outgoing longwave radiation for SEBAL. I followed all steps  but I have problems with the last equation.

```
 function addRout(image) {
  
  var t4 = ee.Number(image.select('Temperature')).pow(ee.Number(4));
  var boltzman = ee.Number(0.0000000567);
  var rout = image.expression(
    '(T4^4 * boltzman * Eo)',
    {'Eo':image.select('Eo'),'T4':t4,'boltzman':boltzman}
     );
  return image.addBands(rout).rename('R_outgoing');
}

var filtered = filtered.map(addRout);
Map.addLayer(filtered.select('R_outgoing'), {palette : ['blue','pink','brown','orange','yellow','green']}, 'R outgoing longwave');
```

The error that emerges:

> R outgoing longwave: Layer error: ImageCollection.mosaic: Error in map:
> Number.pow, argument 'left': Invalid type.
> Expected type: Number.
> Actual type: Image<[Temperature]>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very difficult to help you because you only put a very limited part of your code and any formula for calculating 'R_outgoing'. For these reasons I have to guess or assume some parameters. Inspecting in your **addRout** function, I can see several issues. The t4 variable should be an image, following formula is wrong: `'(T4^4 * boltzman * Eo)'` and **.rename** method is in a wrong place. On the other hand, as I don't have access to your Eo image, I assumed it as constant for running function without any error. So, I modified it as follows. You should change it for adapting to your necessities.

```
function addRout(image) {
  
  var t4 = image.select('Temperature').pow(ee.Number(4));
  var boltzman = ee.Number(0.0000000567);
  var rout = image.expression(
    '(T4**4 * boltzman * Eo)',
    //{'Eo':image.select('Eo'),'T4':t4,'boltzman':boltzman}
    {'Eo': ee.Image.constant(2),
    'T4':t4,
    'boltzman':boltzman}
     ).rename('R_outgoing');

  return image.addBands(rout);
}
```

Complete code can be accessed [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e30874d30a913f6e1ab23a92a38ae10c). After running it in GEE code editor it produces a result without any issue for 'R_outgoing'. However, values are not according with expected because Eo is a fictional constant image and it must be changed for your correct Eo image.

[image]

**Editing Note:**

For obtaining new visualization parameters, click in button inside of red rectangle (Layers combo box) of below image:

[image]

Select Stretch 100% in combo box of following picture:

[image]

Click in Apply and afterward in Import.

[image]

Modified code with new visualization parameters is in this [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/09d24866bed342d53c29801b6fa8823c).

Comment: Thank you. I put your code within mine. Before that I created addEo function for the image collection for the whole year. The function adds a band for each image within a collection for Eo. And then I used map function for each image of the collection. The band is renamed as 'Eo' and therefore I call it within the expression as '''var rout = image.expression(
    '(T4**4 * boltzman * Eo)',
    {'Eo':image.select('Eo'),'T4':t4,'boltzman':boltzman}
     ).rename('R_outgoing');
  return image.addBands(rout);
}'''

Comment: The result for the whole image collection is green. Is it ok? Anyway, thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: It is green in my answer but, in your code, with correct Eo band, image should reflect colors of your palette.

Comment: Mine image also totally green.

Comment: You can create new visualization parameters with the same palette but specifying min and max values for 'R_outgoing'. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: roughly, yes. can you write the min and max values for Rout?

Comment: See my  answer **Editing Note** where is the procedure for getting new visualization parameters for Rout.